# How prove this inequlaity $xyz+4\ge xy+yz+zx$

Tags: inequality

let $x,y,z\in [-1,2]$ show that

> $$xyz+4\ge xy+yz+zx$$

my try let
$$f(x,y,z)=xyz-4-xy-yz-xz=z(xy-y-x)-4$$
and I can't any works.
and  Have nice methods? Thank you

Comment: It is often useful to find the equality case, as that can help you to guess at an approach.

Comment: the critical points seems to be $(0,0,0)$ where minimum occurs and $(2,2,2)$ where maximum occurs. Rest maxima or minima are on boundary.

Comment: @CalvinLin,How can find it,Thank you, and can you post your solution?Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that equality holds when $\{ x, y, z \} = \{-1, 2, 2 \} $ (allowing for permutations).

Show that

$$ (x+1)(y-2)(z-2) + (x-2)(y+1)(z-2) + (x-2)(y-2)(z+1) \geq 0. $$

Equality holds if and only if there are 2 terms that are 2, and a term that is -1. (Explain this yourself.)

Hence, expand and immediately conclude that

$$ xyz + 4 \geq xy + yz + zx . $$

---

As mentioned, the magic of constructing the inequality to consider arises from looking at the equality condition. (Of course, there is also the assumption that this is an olympiad problem and hence has a nice solution.)

Answer (score 0):

This inequality is a linear inequality of $x$, of $y$ and of $z$.

Thus $xyz+4-xy-xz-yz$ gets a minimal value for $\{x,y,z\}\subset\{-1,2\}$

and the rest is easy checking.